# How to make Android Studio's tools:listitem work on the merge tag?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm designing a pretty complicated form on Android, and I'm using `include`s in my fragment. I basically have this:

**include_form.xml**

```xml
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  tools:orientation="vertical"
  tools:parentTag="android.widget.LinearLayout">

    ...

    <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/desired_time_input"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:prompt="@string/time_desired_field"
      android:spinnerMode="dialog"
      tools:listitem="@layout/item_spinner_simple" />

    ...

</merge>
```

which renders beautifully on Android Studio's preview. However, when including this on another file, like this:

**fragment_signup.xml**

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  ...

  <include
    layout="@layout/include_form"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  ...

</LinearLayout>
```

This renders well on a device, or a simulator, but it's not rendered correctly on Android Studio's preview: it basically ignores the `tools:listitem` attribute on the `Spinner`.

This works flawlessly for other components, such as a RecyclerView. Does anyone have an idea, or have I stumbled upon a bug? Thanks!

** Edit 1 **

Tried to add `tools:listitem="@layout/item_spinner_simple"` to the `include` tag and that didn't work.

** Edit 2 **

It really does seem that this is a bug. I've created a bug report:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132686264

Comment: Dd you try adding "tools:listitem="@layout/item_spinner_simple"" in your <include> block?

Comment: @Francesc just tried it. It didn't work :(